# Defines and displays the value of the exp (x) function, for the argument x which is a real number, using the development in a row

Tags: c

In programming language C write a program that
defines and displays the value of the exp (x) function, for the argument x which is a real number, using the development in
a row:
[This is the image of a row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUOGK.jpg)
Calculation is interrupted when the relative value of the sum increment becomes less than the specified accuracy e which is also a real number.

So guys i am new at C and programming so i need to ask is this right for this assignment. Thanks.

This is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) 
{
    double x1,e,x,sum=0.0;
    int n=0;
    printf("Unesite vrednost x = ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("Unesite vrednost e = ");
    scanf("%lf",&e);

    x1=1;
    do {
        sum += x1;
        x1  *= (x/++n);
    }  while (x1 > e);
    printf("sum=%lf,\nexp=%lf\n",sum,exp(x));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the sample inputs used.

Comment: What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: For inputs x=3 and e=0.000001 outputs are sum=20.085536 and exp=20.085536...

Comment: What is your question?